# Conectar cubo de analysis services a power bi por IP

Tags: sql-server, powerbi

Tengo un cubo de analysis services en un servidor de base de datos en una red local. No logro conectar por live connection a power bi con un host remoto usando la IP como servidor para la consulta de datos. ¿Puede de alguna manera conectarse?[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido pero esto es Stack Overflow en español, traduce tu pregunta,  da un [Recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y revisa [Cómo Preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que puedas formular una pregunta que sea aceptada por la comunidad.

Comment: Bienvenido. Puedes indicar, cual es el error que estas obteniendo.

Comment: "No se ha podido conectar al servidor de analysis services porque se agotó el timepo de espera de conexion o el nombre del servidor es incorrecto", En fuentes SQL server si me permite con autenticacion

Comment: No comprendo bien, tu server es local o es remoto ?

Comment: Es servidor Remoto

Answer (score -1):

Hola la forma como puedes hacerlo es de la siguiente forma.
Primero debes tener un usuario windows local en el servidor de analysis services con una contraseña

Luego crear el mismo usuario con la misma contraseña en la maquina del usuario
Darle permiso a ese usuario a tus cubos o modelos tabulares

Teniendo creado lo indicado en los pasos anteriores tienes 2 opciones

La primera es iniciar sesion en la maquina del usuario con esa nueva cuenta local

La segunda es abriendo powerBI como otro usuario, existen varias formas una es entrando a la carpeta donde se encuentra el archivo exe de powerbi y hacer clic con el boton derecho del mouse y seleccionar ejecutar como otro usuario, otra es gpedit configurando la apertura con otros usuarios desde el menu inicio
como hacer eso te comparto un link de youtube donde lo explican muy bien

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Eu3l5t4U6K8

Espero te sirva

Saludos